# Turning Specific Tabs in a google sheet into PDFs and saving them in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script

``I am having trouble pasting in format and the values into the temporary sheet. The cells that are being copied over to the temporary sheet are formulaic. All I need are the fixed values. Below is the code I have been working with and I keep getting caught up on the copyto portion. Does anyone know of a way to paste in just values? I'd like to keep the format of the tabs I am pasting into the temp sheet before saving it to the folder

```
function saveColoredTabsAsPDF() 
{ var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets(); var folderId = "_____________"; // Replace with the ID of the folder where you want to save the PDFs

for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) { var sheet = sheets[i]; var tabColor = sheet.getTabColor();
// Check if the tab color matches the desired color (e.g., green)
if (tabColor == "#93c47d") { // Replace with the hex code of the desired color
  try {
    // Export the sheet as a temporary Google Sheets file



    var temporarySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Temporary Spreadsheet");
    var temporarySheet = temporarySpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
      temporarySheet.setName("Billable Leads"); // Rename the sheet

    sheet.copyTo(temporarySpreadsheet);

    //temporarySpreadsheet.deleteSheet(temporarySheet);
    
    
    // Convert the temporary Google Sheets file to PDF
    var pdfContent = temporarySpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf');
    
    // Create PDF file in the specified folder with sheet name
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    folder.createFile(pdfContent.setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf"));
    
    // Commenting out the deletion of the temporary Google Sheets file
    // DriveApp.getFileById(temporarySpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error occurred while processing sheet: " + sheet.getName() + ". Error: " + error.toString());
  }
}
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In the current stage, `getTabColor()` is one of the deprecated methods. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getTabColor()) In the current stage, `getTabColorObject()` is used instead of it.
- About `temporarySheet.setName("Billable Leads");` and `sheet.copyTo(temporarySpreadsheet);`, in this case, the sheet name is not set to the copied sheet. I think that this might not be the main issue.
- I think that in your script, the default empty sheet and the copied sheet are included in the new Google Spreadsheet. I guessed that you might have wanted to use only the copied sheet.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and set `folderId`, and save the script.

```js
function saveColoredTabsAsPDF() {
  var folderId = "_____________"; // Replace with the ID of the folder where you want to save the PDFs

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var tabColorObj = sheet.getTabColorObject();
    if (tabColorObj.getColorType() != SpreadsheetApp.ColorType.UNSUPPORTED && tabColorObj.asRgbColor().asHexString() == "#93c47d") {
      try {
        var temp = sheet.copyTo(spreadsheet);
        var tempRange = temp.getDataRange();
        tempRange.copyTo(tempRange, { contentsOnly: true });
        var temporarySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Temporary Spreadsheet");
        temp.copyTo(temporarySpreadsheet).setName("Billable Leads");
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        temporarySpreadsheet.deleteSheet(temporarySpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
        spreadsheet.deleteSheet(temp);
        var pdfContent = temporarySpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf');
        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
        folder.createFile(pdfContent.setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf"));
      } catch (error) {
        Logger.log("Error occurred while processing sheet: " + sheet.getName() + ". Error: " + error.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this modification, the following flow is used.

1. Copy the existing sheet to the same Spreadsheet as a temporal sheet. In this case, the cell styles are also copied.
2. Removing the formulas in the sheet.
3. Copy the sheet to the created new Spreadsheet, and change the sheet name.
4. Delete the 1st empty sheet and the temporal sheet.
5. Exported a Spreadsheet as a PDF file.

#### References:

- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [copyTo(destination, options) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))